# How to Specify different Process settings for two different spiders in CrawlerProcess Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have **two spiders which I want to execute in parallel**. I used the `CrawlerProcess` instance and its `crawl` method to acheieve this. However, I want to **specify different output file**, ie `FEED_URI` **for each spider in the same process**. I tried to loop the spiders and run them as shown below. Though two different output files are generated, the **process terminates as soon as the second spider completes execution**. If the first spider completes crawling before the second one, I get the desired output. However, if the second spider finishes crawling first, then it doesn't wait for the first spider to complete. How could I actually fix this?

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spider_loader.list():
    setting['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'json'
    setting['LOG_LEVEL'] = 'INFO'
    setting['FEED_URI'] = spider_name+'.json'
    setting['LOG_FILE'] = spider_name+'.log'
    process = CrawlerProcess(setting)
    print("Running spider %s" % spider_name)
    process.crawl(spider_name)

process.start()
print("Completed")
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `process` object inside the loop. Please look at the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706005/crawlerprocess-vs-crawlerrunner

Comment: How else could I write the output to two separate Json Files?

Comment: See this article https://kirankoduru.github.io/python/multiple-scrapy-spiders.html

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with my code, however if I do setting.update({
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': spider_name + ".json",
        'LOG_FILE': spider_name + '.log',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'
    })
alone in the loop it works fine and generates the appropriate json output. But the log files aren't proper. Is there a way to make log files proper too

Answer (score 1):

According to scrapy [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) using single `CrawlerProcess` for multiple spiders should look like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    ...

class Spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.crawl(Spider2)
process.start()
```

setting.. settings on per spider basis can be done using [`custom_settings` spider attribute](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?settings-per-spider#settings-per-spider)

Scrapy has a group of modules that can't be set on per spider basis (only per 
`CrawlerProcess`). 
modules that using Logging, SpiderLoader and twisted Reactor related settings - already initialized before Scrapy read spider `custom_settings`.

When you call `scrapy crawl ....` from command line tool - in fact you create [single `CrawlerProcess`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/3d027fb578532d504b3dbfaa77a06c3560f85d3c/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#L15-L29) for single spider defined on command args.

> process terminates as soon as the second spider completes execution.

If you used the same spider versions previously launched by `scrapy crawl...` this is not expected.

Comment: How Exactly could I modify the above code to create individual logs too?

Comment: Logs can't be individual in this case.
In this configuration there will be a single logger object per crawlerprocess (due to specifics of logging implementation in scrapy source code).
The only reliable ways to do it: 1 by using `scrapy crawl ..` command line tool separately for each spider as you previously did.  2. By creating 2 separate scripts and split execution into 2 crawler processes (it is nearly the same).